# How to limit ActivityResultContract.GetContent to media (image or video)

Tags: android, registerforactivityresult, getcontent, activityresultcontracts

Is there a way to make ActivityResultContract.GetContent filter only media files?

```
    private val selectMediaResultLauncher = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.GetContent()) { uri: Uri? ->
    // Do something with the uri
}
```

Tried to use:

```
    selectMediaResultLauncher.launch("image/* video/*")
```

But no luck.

Thanks for assiting.

Answer (score 1):

You can use OpenDocument()

```
private val selectMediaResultLauncher = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.OpenDocument()) { uri ->
        // Do something with the uri
    }
```

and:

```
selectMediaResultLauncher.launch(arrayOf("image/*", "video/*"))
```